# How to use an OBJ file?

Tags: c++

I encountered a very interesting thing.  Somebody gave me only an OBJ file, even not C/C++ header file. But I have a few signatures of the functions in the OBJ file. Can I use only these signatures and obj file to Link the code in the OBJ file to my app?

If it works, how I can do it? I get not point now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you ask that somebody?

Comment: .obj is basicly the same as .lib. The difference is that the .lib file is used as container to hold multiple .obj files. In conclusion, you can use it as it would be a .lib file.

Comment: to GMan, I don't know how to describe, just a person.  He asked me to do.        //////////////////////////    to ruslik, Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

During the link step, simply add the object file to the sources. How to do this varies with the compiler and linker used, but it may be as simple as adding it to the compilation command line.

Note that C++ uses different name-mangling rules from C, and you may need to use `extern "C"`.

Comment: I use Visual C++ 2008.  Can you tell where can I place the OBj file and How to set the project property?

Comment: I have never used any Microsoft graphical development tool in any real capacity, and so cannot tell you where the object file must be listed.

Comment: MSVC - Add it by open properties on the project, config properties, linker, input, add it to the list of Additional Dependancies

Comment: And add the signatures as externs to make them available, basically make your own header for it with just the bits you need.

Comment: Thanks you all!  But I try Greg Domjan's method, it return an error.         fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x78B7

Comment: That would be a problem with the object file; talk to whoever provided it.